# Variable in regex python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace the nth position of false with true. And this works if I change the %s in the quantifier with just any 0-9 digit. However when I insert a variable it doesn't work anymore and I get returned that the variable is interpreted as an empty string (''). I am guessing it has to do with that regex uses a string as pattern. Also when I insert etc.{' + 'str(variable)' +'}etc, it says that the accolades aren't closed.
Could anyone tell me the correct way to use variables in conjunction with regex?

I have the following code:

```
pos = str(lijst2.index(x))

new_string = re.sub(r'^((.*?False.*?){%s})False' % pos, r'\1True', new_string)
```

Pos example: `3` 
New string example: `False, False, False, False, False` 
What I want: `False, False, False, True, False`

This works perfectly fine:

```
nieuwstring = re.sub(r'^((.*?False.*?){3})False' r'\1True', nieuwstring)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
import re

input = 'False, False, False, False, False'

pos = 2

pattern = r'(?<=^(?:False, ){%i})False' % pos

output = re.sub(pattern, r'True', input)

print(output) # False, False, True, False, False
```

[Live Demo](https://repl.it/IUPv/4)